# How to get user who pushed forced with git?

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, bitbucket-server

I use git version system on a bitbucket server. Someone was pushed commits with **force**. Can I get this committer? How can I find this user? Is it possible with git commands like 'git log --full-history, git log --reflog or vs ...'.

If can i get payload.json like as below, I can see commits that are forced or not? How can i get this json?

https://gist.github.com/nevik/5939946

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the link below, I think it would help

https://github.com/kyanny/git-hooks-detect-force-update